# Prevent angular from copying attributes when replace=true

Tags: angularjs

The following directive:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h1>Foo bar</h1>'
    };
});
```

With the following usage:

```
<my:directive foo="bar"></my:directive>
```

Renders the following HTML:

```
<my:directive foo="bar"><h1>Foo bar</h1></my:directive>
```

Since I want to replace my directive with the provided template I set `replace:true`. This produces the following HTML:

```
<h1 foo="bar">Foo bar</h1>
```

Note that Angular copies my directive's attributes to the template elements (the `foo="bar"`). How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually remove the attributes in the link function of the directive:

```
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<h1>Foo bar</h1>',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
                elm.removeAttr('foo');
            }
        };
    });
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DpDGT/) with this directive working in your situation.

EDIT: You can extend this to remove all attributes dynamically with a simple loop:

```
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            template: '<h1>Foo bar</h1>',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
                for(var attr in attrs.$attr){
                    elm.removeAttr(attr);
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: This is not a dynamic method to remove attributes, is there a generic way to remove all the attributes of the directive once they've been elaborated?

Comment: I understand your question but am disappointed by the downvote. My answer works for the question asked, and it's quite simple to extend it to remove all attributes. See edit.

Comment: Thank you. It is always better to post an answer which works correctly in most of the cases though :)